# Comparar e imprimir dados separados por virgula

Tags: c#, winforms, console

Não to conseguindo fazer a comparação com os dados do bloco de notas. Esses dados são inseridos tudo em linha e separado por;
Em suma, entra

> valor;descrição;dia;mes;ano

```
if (dia == "" || mes == "" || ano == "") 
{
  ERRO erro = new ERRO();
  erro.Show();
} else {
  using(StreamReader lerentrada = new StreamReader(@ "escreveentrada.txt"))
  {


    string[] leitor = lerentrada.ReadLine().Split(';');
    if (leitor[0] != null) 
    {
      while ((leitor[0] = lerentrada.ReadLine()) != null) 
      {
        if (leitor[2] == TDia.Text) 
        {
          if (leitor[3] == Tmes.Text)
          {
            if (leitor[4] == Tano.Text) 
            {
              TRelatorio.AppendText($ "{leitor}{Environment.NewLine}");
            }
          }
        }
      }
    } else {


    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Algum problema específico? O arquivo é muito grande? O computador tem muita restrição de memória?

Comment: Na verdade, acho que não to conseguindo ler os dados corretamente. Porque o dados do Textbox até que entra certinho, sabe? Mas, na hora de comparar, não compara.

Comment: Está lendo direitinho, posso te garantir porque é o *frmework* que o faz e ele não erra, o problema está em algo depois disso.

Comment: Entendi, só que será que to comparando corretamente então?

Comment: Esse é o problema da pergunta, só você sabe.

Comment: Complicou. 
Mas eu fiz a inserção dos dados desse jeito conforme eu disse
Valor;Descrição;dia;mes;ano

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que o problema seja no seu while.

No trecho:

```
while ((leitor[0] = lerentrada.ReadLine()) != null)
```

Você ta colocando toda leitura da linha do arquivo na primeira posição do vetor(a posição 0), porém logo após você compara as posições 1,2 e 3 do vetor.
Do jeito que está, somente a posição [0] do vetor leitor está sendo atualizado.

Altere o código como abaixo e deve funcionar.

```
while ((leitor[] = lerentrada.ReadLine().Split(',')) != null)
```

Answer (score 0):

O problema está na forma como está a ler a informação.

Penso que assim conseguirá chegar lá:

```
if (dia == "" || mes == "" || ano == "") 
{
    ERRO erro = new ERRO();
    erro.Show();
} 
else 
{
    using(StreamReader lerentrada = new StreamReader(@ "escreveentrada.txt"))
    {
        string linha = string.Empty;

        while ((linha = lerentrada.ReadLine()) != null) 
        {
            string[] leitor = linha.Split(';');

            if(leitor[0].Length == 0)
                continue;

            if (leitor[2] == TDia.Text && leitor[3] == Tmes.Text && leitor[4] == Tano.Text)
                TRelatorio.AppendText($"{leitor}{Environment.NewLine}");
        }
    }
}
```